# GNU Mailman: Too many open files/No module

Tags: python, file, module, centos6, mailman

I'm running CentOS6 with Mailman. Imported the old Mailman list from the old server via Plesk. Currently I'm running into several errors. Installed version of Python is 2.7.8. Already fixed some of them, but not all.
Already modified /etc/security/limits.conf:

```
* hard nofile 65535
* soft nofile 65535
* hard locks 65535
* soft locks 65535
* soft default_process_limit = 10
```

The Errorlog still shows following:

```
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1042): Traceback (most recent call last):
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1042):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner", line 278, in <module>
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1042):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner", line 238, in main
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1042):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Queue/Runner.py", line 71, in run
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1042):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Queue/Runner.py", line 95, in _oneloop
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1042):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Queue/Switchboard.py", line 194, in files
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1042): OSError :  [Errno 23] Too many open files in system: '/var/spool/mailman/in' 
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1039): Traceback (most recent call last):
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1039):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner", line 278, in <module>
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1039):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner", line 238, in main
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1039):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Queue/Runner.py", line 71, in run
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1039):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Queue/Runner.py", line 95, in _oneloop
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1039):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Queue/Switchboard.py", line 194, in files
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1039): OSError :  [Errno 23] Too many open files in system: '/var/spool/mailman/archive' 
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1044): Traceback (most recent call last):
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1044):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner", line 278, in <module>
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1044):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner", line 238, in main
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1044):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Queue/Runner.py", line 71, in run
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1044):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Queue/Runner.py", line 95, in _oneloop
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1044):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Queue/Switchboard.py", line 194, in files
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1044): OSError :  [Errno 23] Too many open files in system: '/var/spool/mailman/out' 
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1045): Traceback (most recent call last):
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1045):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner", line 278, in <module>
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1045):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner", line 238, in main
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1045):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Queue/Runner.py", line 71, in run
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1045):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Queue/Runner.py", line 95, in _oneloop
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1045):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Queue/Switchboard.py", line 194, in files
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1045): OSError :  [Errno 23] Too many open files in system: '/var/spool/mailman/virgin' 
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1040): Traceback (most recent call last):
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1040):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner", line 278, in <module>
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1040):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner", line 238, in main
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1040):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Queue/Runner.py", line 71, in run
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1040):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Queue/Runner.py", line 95, in _oneloop
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1040):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Queue/Switchboard.py", line 194, in files
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1040): OSError :  [Errno 23] Too many open files in system: '/var/spool/mailman/bounces' 
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1043): Traceback (most recent call last):
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1043):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner", line 278, in <module>
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1043):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner", line 238, in main
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1043):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Queue/Runner.py", line 71, in run
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1043):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Queue/Runner.py", line 95, in _oneloop
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1043):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Queue/Switchboard.py", line 194, in files
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1043): OSError :  [Errno 23] Too many open files in system: '/var/spool/mailman/news' 
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1041): Traceback (most recent call last):
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1041):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner", line 278, in <module>
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1041):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner", line 238, in main
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1041):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Queue/Runner.py", line 71, in run
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1041):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Queue/Runner.py", line 95, in _oneloop
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1041):   File "/usr/lib/mailman/Mailman/Queue/Switchboard.py", line 194, in files
Dec 22 04:06:43 2014 qrunner(1041): OSError :  [Errno 23] Too many open files in system: '/var/spool/mailman/commands' 
Dec 22 04:06:44 2014 qrunner(8563): Cannot import runner module   Mailman.Queue.NewsRunner 
Dec 22 04:06:44 2014 qrunner(8563): /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/datetime.so: cannot open shared object file: Too many open files in system 
Dec 22 04:06:44 2014 qrunner(8569): Cannot import runner module   Mailman.Queue.ArchRunner 
Dec 22 04:06:44 2014 qrunner(8569): cannot import name Header 
Dec 22 04:06:44 2014 qrunner(8565): Cannot import runner module   Mailman.Queue.CommandRunner 
Dec 22 04:06:44 2014 qrunner(8565): No module named nonmultipart
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not only need to raise the ulimit, but also enable the kernel to use serve more open files. The tool 'sysctl' is the key for this.

I have no clue on how to change this using Plesk. Just use a command shell and follow these instructions:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/

Cheers!

Comment: I did not modified the sysctl in that way, but increased the file-max already to 262144. So that's already fixed.